# Modify Flask-Login @Login_Required Decorator

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I would like to change the default Flask-Login `@login_required` so that it will check a database as to whether a user is banned or not.

I am aware I could create a custom decorator to check my database and add it to all my views, however this would be less useful due to the number of views I have; it wouldn't be convenient.

Is this possible or not? Thanks.

Comment: maybe have `is_authenticated` return a property `is_banned` instead of just `True`?. use `@property` decorater to do logic

Comment: Your [user class](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class) has `is_authenticated` and `is_active` properties. Use one to `return False` if the user is banned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next approach:

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user_if_not_banned(user_id):        
    user = ... # Load user from DB
    return user if not user.is_banned else None
```